# How to print PDF file already opened in QLPreviewController using print button?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6.1, uidocumentinteraction, qlpreviewcontroller

I get binary array then convert it and save in Documents folder and then showed in QLPreviewController. I have seen the right button on the tool bar of QLPreviewController.

I want to print that is in the preview right now. But when i tab error occurs

```
*** Assertion failure in -[UIDocumentInteractionController setURL:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-2380.17/UIDocumentInteractionController.m:960
```

Also please guide me about printing that document. I have read about UIPrintInteractionController.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why this Error occurs because you have set the URL wrong. 
You are setting url like that;

```
/Users/akrama2/Library/Application%20Support/iPhone%20Simulator/6.1/Applications/59356D13-C021-431F-A5D2-B8CD16E2B301/Documents/Application_Report.pdf
```

Where as UIDocumentationController task URL as:

```
file://localhost/Users/akrama2/Library/Application%20Support/iPhone%20Simulator/6.1/Applications/59356D13-C021-431F-A5D2-B8CD16E2B301/Documents/Application_Report.pdf
```

This minor mistake will made you mad ;)